# Second hand game

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I recently purchased a second hand copy of Call of Duty Black Ops. I have tried to install it via steam but when it asks me to input the game key it tells me that the game key has already been used under a different account to mine. Is there any way round this??

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Please don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the Arqade SE!

Unfortunately, when it comes to disc based PC games requiring a Product Key / CD Key, there is no legal way around this.  A product key may only be used once as it is used to essentially "register" the game as yours, or in this case, the other persons.

Sorry about that! :(

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I figured that might be the case!